# Chmod equivalence of +x and 0755

Tags: bash, shell

Just curious, are these two completely equivalent?

```
chmod +x file
chmod 0755 file
```

Comment: No, because +x just adds x to the current mask for everybody, not influencing rw, while 0755 changes the whole mask.

Comment: -1 You would have found this out if you read the man page for chmod and possibly the wpedia page for Filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`chmod 0755 file` is equivalent to u=rwx (4+2+1),go=rx (4+1 & 4+1). The 0 specifies default special modes (see comment below). See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for more info (including tables describing u,g,o,a and r,w,x,s,t,).

So in other words: No, they're not equivalent since 0755 contains more flags.

See also: [chmod man page](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Comment: That's not accurate. The 0 specifies set UID (4), get GID (2) and sticky bit (1) in the first of the 4 numbers. If omitted, it assumes a padded 0 on the front.

Comment: @iandouglas But "if omitted, it assumes a padded 0 on the front", should then mean that 0 is the default? So in other words, you're just saying that it should say "no special special modes" ?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes, 0 is an implied default, so "755" should be the same as "0755"

Comment: @iandouglas post edited

Answer (score 6):

Chmod *number* sets the permissions to exactly that number. Chmod *relative* only changes the requested bits. A file whose permissions were 000 before `chmod +x` will now be 111. Conversely, a file whose permissions were 0775 before (read+write+execute for owner and group; read and execute for others) will be unchanged by `chmod +x`, whereas setting the mode to exactly 0755 will change the 020 bit (remove write access for group).

Answer (score 3):

No, because `chmod 755` also sets various read and write flags.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent because `chmod+x` will set the file permission to execute for the current user and `chmod 0755` will allow full permission to owner,  read and execute permission for groups and for others. And regarding first digit here according to man page:

```
0 -> selects attributes for the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and save text image (1)S
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file was already chmod 644, then, yes, they are effectively equal. It's better to explicitly list the bits you want to set though, using something like `a+x`